# Dismiss SoftKeyboard in Flex Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, soft-keyboard, flex-mobile

The Flex `InteractiveObject` has has a `requestSoftKeyboard()` method that pops up the Soft Keyboard.

How can I do the opposite and send it back?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Flex 4.6, you can dismiss by setting

```
stage.focus = null;
```

Please read more here:
[open soft keyboard in a mobile Flex application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html)

Answer (score 1):

For example, say your InteractiveObject is a TextInput, then you can keep it from popping up with the following:

```
private function onActivating(event:SoftKeyboardEvent):void 
{
           event.preventDefault();
}           


<s:TextInput softKeyboardActivating="onActivating(event)" />
```

Or you can use

```
<s:TextInput needsSoftKeyboard = "False"/>
```

**EDIT:**

You can send it back with the following:

Listen for the event when you want it to close (like hitting the "enter" key) and then use the setFocus property to change the focus to another component:

```
private function CloseKeyboard():void
{
hidesoftkeyboard.setFocus();
}`

<s:TextInput id="txtinput"/>
<s:Button id="hidesoftkeyboard" click=CloseKeyboard();>
```

**UPDATE**

Following the 4.6 update to Flex - there are new softkeyboard techniques chronicled [here.](http://devgirl.org/2011/11/29/flex-mobile-development-flex-4-6-cool-new-soft-keyboard-features-sample-w-source/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a way to dismiss it programatically. Not prevent it from appearing.

Comment: Hm, that's kind of a hack. I'll give it a go and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it is a hack - but the problem is Flex doesn't deal with the native Android API, and has to cross-reference. Every release gets better, but we're still stuck on a few of these pesky issues. Check [this](http://theorynine.com/labs/close-air-android-keyboard/) for more info.