# Flex 4.6 hide/dismiss softkeyboard

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm having some issues with the softkeyboard behaviour in flex 4.6 and air 3.1

I have a list with a search bar on top. When a user selects the TextInput component the softkeyboard pops up like it should.
Now when the user is done typing his text and presses the return (or the done/search/...) key I want the softkeyboard to disappear.

What I've tried so far:

- I've set the returnKeyLabel property to "done" and the button shows
  up accordingly. However it only dismisses the keyboard on Android, on
  IOS the keyboard just stays up.
- I then tried by not setting the returnKeyLabel and manually
  catching the Return key and setting the focus to another element that
  does not require a softkeyboard but that didn't work either.
- I also tried by dispatching my own "faked" click events when the Return key was pressed but this also didn't work.

As part of searching about this problem I found this [Dismiss SoftKeyboard in Flex Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231457/dismiss-softkeyboard-in-flex-mobile) but that didn't work either. Or at least not in flex 4.6

Now does anyone know of a good way to hide the softkeyboard or make the returnKeyLabel "done" work on IOS that will work with flex 4.6/air 3.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<s:TextInput prompt="First Name" returnKeyLabel="done" enter="handlerFunction()"/>  
private function handlerFunction():void{
    stage.focus = null
}
```

Comment: Glad its working, when you set a returnKeyLabel you get access to an enter handler that should let you do whatever you need.

Answer (score 3):

For flex mobile android apps I have mimicked the intuitive ios way of tapping on the background to remove the softkeyboard as follows:

```
import spark.components.supportClasses.*
        protected function application1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            if(event.target is StyleableTextField || event.target is StyleableStageText){
                // ignore because came from a textInput
            }else{
                stage.focus = null
                // to remove the softkeyboard
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:TextInput prompt="First Name" returnKeyLabel="done" enter="{stage.focus = null}"/>
```

This is the same as Francis' answer, but it saves having to make a new function